# Passing two awk columns into a while read command

Tags: bash, unix, awk, gawk

`SampleFile`:

```
Two Words,Extra
```

My code:

```
cat SampleFile | awk -F "," '{print $1" "$2}' | while read var1 var2;
do
    echo $var1
done
```

This will print out only `Two` and `var2` will take `Words`. Is there a way so that I can pass `Two Words` into `var1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use awk for this. Bash has a built-in variable to determine where words are split:

```
while IFS=, read -r var1 var2; do
    echo "$var1"
done < SampleFile
```

`IFS` is set to `,`, so word splitting takes place at commas.

Instead of piping to the `while` loop, I use redirection, which has the advantage of not spawning a subshell.

---

A remark: you don't need `cat` in this context. Awk can take a file name as an argument, so

```
cat SampleFile | awk -F "," '{print $1" "$2}'
```

becomes

```
awk -F "," '{print $1, $2}' SampleFile
```

Also, when using `print`, you don't need to explicitly introduce spaces: if you comma-separate your fields, awk will replace the comma by the value of the `OFS` (output field separator) variable, which defaults to a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
...| while read var1; do echo $var1 done
```

Comment: But is there a way to make this work with both the var1 and var2 the reason being this piece of script will be used to make insert queries.

Comment: you can escape the space : echo 'aaa\ bbb'  | while read a b ; do echo $a; done

Comment: or translate the space : echo aaa bbb  | tr " " "#" | while read a b ; do echo $a; done | tr "#" " "